# Linux kernel module Makefile can't include relative paths

Tags: c, linux, makefile, linux-kernel, gnu-make

I'm trying to build Linux kernel module:

```
KBUILD_EXTRA_SYMBOLS := ../../Module.symvers
KBUILD_EXTRA_SYMBOLS := ../../dir0/Module.symvers
KDIR = ../../../../kernel/linux-4.9

INCLUDES = \
     -I../dir1/dir2/dir3  \
     -I../dir1/dir2 \
     -I../dir1

EXTRA_CFLAGS += $(INCLUDES)

PWD = $(shell pwd)

TARGET = some_module

obj-m := $(TARGET).o

all: default clean
default:
     make $(INCLUDES) -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
     @rm -f *.o .*.cmd .*.flags *.mod.c *.order
     @rm -f .*.*.cmd *.symvers *~ *.*~ TODO.*
     @rm -fR .tmp*
     @rm -rf .tmp_versions
disclean: clean
     @rm -f *.ko
```

But it can't locate files in relative paths e.g. like `fatal error: some_header.h: No such file or directory`. When I use absolute paths it works well, but I need to do relative addressing from current directory in this project. What's wrong?
Sorry if obvious.

Comment: Can you try re-writing the paths so that they include `$(src)`? `$(src)` points to the path where the Makefile is located.

Comment: @peachykeen Sorry, didn't get it... Please clarify what you mean

Comment: If you have a Makefile in `dir2` and you want to reach `file` in `dir1` that is one level higher in the directory tree, try the following as your  path: `$(src)/../file`

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18143/how-to-include-local-header-files-in-linux-kernel-module. Cannot find analogue question on Stack Overflow, but it could be quite useful here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Linux kernel uses Kbuild to make modules. This framework differs from normal makefile conventions, so while they are both interpreted by GNU make, one needs to be aware of the differences. [Documentation for Makefiles using Kbuild can be found here](https://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/kbuild/makefiles.txt) and [documentation for building external kernel modules can be found here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt).

A few important points, relevant to your problem, from the documentation are quoted below.

From `makefiles.txt`:

> --- 3.10 Special Rules
>
> Special rules are used when the kbuild infrastructure does not provide the required support. A typical example is header files
>   generated during the build process. Another example are the
>   architecture-specific Makefiles which need special rules to prepare
>   boot images etc. Special rules are written as normal Make rules. Kbuild is not executing in the directory where the Makefile is located, so all
>   special rules shall provide a relative path to prerequisite files
>   and target files. Two variables are used when defining special rules:
>
> ~`$(src)`~
>
> `$(src)` is a relative path which points to the directory where the Makefile is located. Always use `$(src)` when referring to files located in the `src` tree.
>
> ~`$(obj)`~
>
> `$(obj)` is a relative path which points to the directory where the target is saved. Always use `$(obj)` when referring to generated files.

From `modules.txt`:

> --- 4.3 Several Subdirectories
>
> kbuild can handle files that are spread over several directories.
>     Consider the following example:
>
> ```
>   .   
>   |__ src     
>   |   |__ complex_main.c  
>   |   |__ hal     
>   |       |__ hardwareif.c
>   |       |__ include     
>   |           |__ hardwareif.h    
>   |__ include
>       |__ complex.h
> ```
>
> To build the module complex.ko, we then need the following  kbuild
>   file:
>
> ```
>    --> filename: Kbuild
>    obj-m := complex.o
>    complex-y := src/complex_main.o
>    complex-y += src/hal/hardwareif.o
>
>    ccflags-y := -I$(src)/include
>    ccflags-y += -I$(src)/src/hal/include
> ```
>
> As you can see, kbuild knows how to handle object files located     in
>   other directories. The trick is to specify the directory  relative to
>   the kbuild file's location. That being said, this     is NOT recommended
>   practice.
>
> For the header files, kbuild must be explicitly told where to   look.
>   When kbuild executes, the current directory is always the     root of the
>   kernel tree (the argument to "-C") and therefore an   absolute path is
>   needed. `$(src)` provides the absolute path by    pointing to the
>   directory where the currently executing kbuild    file is located.

Thus, your Makefile should look like the following:

```
KBUILD_EXTRA_SYMBOLS := $(src)/../../Module.symvers
KBUILD_EXTRA_SYMBOLS := $(src)/../../dir0/Module.symvers
KDIR = $(src)/../../../../kernel/linux-4.9

INCLUDES = \
     -I$(src)/../dir1/dir2/dir3  \
     -I$(src)/../dir1/dir2 \
     -I$(src)/../dir1

EXTRA_CFLAGS += $(INCLUDES)

PWD = $(shell pwd)

TARGET = some_module

obj-m := $(TARGET).o

all: default clean
default:
     make $(INCLUDES) -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
     @rm -f *.o .*.cmd .*.flags *.mod.c *.order
     @rm -f .*.*.cmd *.symvers *~ *.*~ TODO.*
     @rm -fR .tmp*
     @rm -rf .tmp_versions
disclean: clean
     @rm -f *.ko
```

Comment: For some reason it works only with `KDIR = $(src)../../../../kernel/linux-4.9` but not with `KDIR = $(src)/../../../../kernel/linux-4.9`

Comment: Thanks for hinting at the kernel docs here! Now according to `makefiles.txt` `src` is relative. But relative to what? The source tree or the build tree? According to `modules.txt` `src` is absolute, which sounds like a contradiction. I can build https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8188eus/tree/v5.7.6.1 as is with linux 4.9 and `O=build`, but I have to replace `-I$(src)` by `-I$(srctree)/$(src)` to make it find its includes with linux 5.4. So it looks like `src` changed from absolute to relative meanwhile.