# How should I set extra include path for linux kernel module build?

Tags: makefile, linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

This is the Makefile that I'm using for cross-buildig a kernel module.

```
export CROSS_COMPILE:=aarch64-none-linux-gnu-
export ARCH:=arm64
obj-m += chr_drv_ex1.o
export KDIR:=linux-source-5.4.0
#EXTRA_CFLAGS=-I../../qemu-5.1.0/hw/misc
#ccflags-y=-I../../qemu-5.1.0/hw/misc

all: test_chr_drv map_hugetlb test_ioctl_drv
    make ARCH=$(ARCH) CROSS_COMPILE=$(CROSS_COMPILE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make ARCH=$(ARCH) CROSS_COMPILE=$(CROSS_COMPILE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) clean
    rm -f test_chr_drv map_hugetlb test_ioctl_drv

%: %.c
    $(CROSS_COMPILE)gcc $^ -o $@
```

Now in my chr_drv_ex1.c file, I want to include a header file placed in ../../qemu-5.1.0/hw/misc directory. What is the correct method to add this path? I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10176238/how-do-i-add-an-include-path-for-kernel-module-makefile/10177919) and tried setting EXTRA_CFLAGS and ccflags-y but none of them works(those are commented out above). Of course if I use `#include "../../qemu-5.1.0/hw/misc/axpu_regs.h"` in the chr_drv_ex1.c source I can compile it. But I want to use `#include <axpu_regs.h>`.

Comment: My gosh, for achieving what you want to is enough to have line 3 and possible line with `cflags-y`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linux kernel module Makefile can't include relative paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62196308/linux-kernel-module-makefile-cant-include-relative-paths)

Answer (score 0):

I changed the ccflags-y from

```
ccflags-y := -I../../qemu-5.1.0/hw/misc
```

to

```
ccflags-y := -I../../../qemu-5.1.0/hw/misc
```

So the include path should be specified as seen from the kernel make directory (where the Makefile for linux kernel is located. in this case linux-source-5.4.0 directory which is one step below from where I am now).

Comment: Learn about `$(src)` and `$(srctree)` (name of second one I don’t remember by heart, use `git grep ...` to find examples.